# Traffic Jam Java assignment

Tags: java

I need to create a Java program that plays out a game with the following rules;

- There are two teams.
- The "board" starts out like this: i.e. 2 on each team; X X null Y Y.
- Members on the same team can not jump each other.
- Members on the opposite team can jump each other only if there is a blank space behind the opposite team member they are jumping.
- Members on either team can only move forward to a blank space, they can never move backwards.
- The goal is to have them switch places. i.e. Y Y null X X.

Here is my solution with the above example;

X   X   O   Y   Y   - MOVE X

X   O   X   Y   Y   - Y JUMP X

X   Y   X   O   Y   - MOVE Y 

X   Y   O   Y   X   - X JUMP Y

Repeat in reverse..

O   Y   X   Y   X   - X JUMP Y

Y   O   X   Y   X   - MOVE Y 

Y   Y   X   O   X   - Y JUMP X

Y   Y   O   X   X   - MOVE X

I'm not sure how to make this scalable to handle larger team sizes, or if I'm even on the right track. Any help at all on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far;

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int teamSize = 0, i = 0;

    System.out.print("How many members on each team?");
    teamSize = keyboard.nextInt();

    //set board and it's size
    String[] board = new String[(teamSize*2) + 1];

    //set team positions
    int x = 1, y = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < teamSize; i++) {
        board[i] = "X";
        board[i + teamSize + 1] = "Y";
    }
    System.out.print("\nBoard: " + Arrays.toString(board));

    // firstMove - MOVE X
    String pre1move = board[teamSize]; // original center value
    board[i] = board[i-1]; 
    board[i-1] = pre1move;
    System.out.print("\nX moved up: " + Arrays.toString(board));
    // secondMove - Y JUMP X
    // thirdMove - MOVE Y
    // fourthMove - X JUMP Y 

    // repeat pattern in reverse
}
```

Comment: Wait. So what's the actual question you're asking?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to explain as best I could, I need help with direction on how to accomplish the assigned task of getting the program to take the array such as X X null Y Y and reverse it to become Y Y null X X while following the rules above. I'm stuck and not sure on where to go from here.

Comment: Did you randomly try moving and jumping in your hand-written version and stumbled into a solution, or can you articulate some reasons or rules for the moves you've chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty difficult to answer your question without just straight up giving you the code for it.....So, let me see if I can explain the general strategy you should take.

Currently, in your commented out code at the very bottom of your `main` method, you're actually specifying "Okay, this specific guy should specifically move to this space." Now, that works, but only in this exact scenario where you have 2 versus 2. When you attempt to play 3 vs 3, 4 vs 4, etc., you are correct in what you said previously; this won't scale.

What you need to do is set up your code so that you can interrogate one `Player` and it's relation to the other `Player`s and the `Board` itself. You should create `Player` Java classes, and given them instance variables like `Direction` and `Name` so you can identify which direction they are traveling.

Then, with this information, you can ask more general questions at a given point in play for any individual `Player`:

- I am a `Player` X. I'm am travelling `Right`. Can I :
- Step further to the right?

-- Is there another `Player` X in my way?

-- Am I about to go off the end of the board (and therefore in my final position)?

-- etc.

So, if you can pose more generic questions given a `Player`'s current situation, the game scales.

I know that's vague, but like I said, that's about the best you'll get without the exact solution. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks Mike! That's actually exactly what I needed.